# finding the mean for each of the channels (RGB) across an array of images

Tags: python, numpy, mean

How can I find the mean for each of the channels (RGB) across an array of images?

For example `train_dataset[0]['image'].shape` is `(600, 800, 3)` and `len(train_dataset)` is 720 meaning it includes 720 images of dimension 600x800 and 3 channels. `train_dataset[0]['image']` is an `ndarray`.

I am looking to end up with 3 numbers each representing the mean for each of the channels across all these 720 images.

I have this very dumb solution but I wonder if there's a better solution?
[image]

I also did it this other way and got almost the same answer:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could probably be more elegant, but here's an idea:

```
mean[:, :, 0:2] = np.mean(imgs[:, :, :, 0:2], axis=0)
```